# getting the string of enum

Tags: java, enums

I have the following enum:

```
 public static enum OpCode {
    a((byte) 0x0),
    b((byte)0x18),
    c((byte)0x1A);

    private byte value; 

    private  OpCode (byte value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    byte getValue() {
        return value;
    }
```

if I have the value x = 0x18
how can I get the string  'b'?

this is what I tried:

```
    System.out.println(OpCode.values()[x]);
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Linear search, perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

You can implement static method such as `fromByte` :

```
public enum OpCode {
... truncated
    public static OpCode fromByte(byte x) {
        for(OpCode oc : values()) {
           if (oc.getValue() == x) {
               return oc;
           }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown OpCode value: " + x);
    }
}
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
OpCode oc = OpCode.fromByte(x);
```

Answer (score 4):

Either linear search as Joe C suggest in its comment or use a `Map` to store `OpCode` instances by `Byte value`.

```
 public static enum OpCode {

    a((byte) 0x0),
    b((byte)0x18),
    c((byte)0x1A);

    private final byte value;

    private final static Map<Byte, OpCode> opCodesByByte;

    static {
          opCodesByByte = new HashMap<>();
          for (OpCode opCode : values()) {
             opCodesByByte.put(opCode.value, opCode);   
          }
    }

   ...    
  }
```

And also add a `static` method in `OpCode` to provide the search method :

```
public static OpCode of(byte value){
   return opCodesByByte.get(value);
}
```

Note that in this implementation, it returns `null` if no matching.

Comment: I would make the map `final` +1

Comment: And you are right. Thanks. By the way, the `value` member should also be. I updated.

Comment: @davidxxx I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46963999/instantiate-class-by-passing-required-parameter-depending-on-which-environment-y) related to design of enum. Wanted to see if you can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop the enum:

```
    byte x = 0x18;
    for (OpCode opCode : OpCode.values()) {
        if (x == opCode.getValue()) {
            System.out.println(opCode);
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, build a map like this:

```
    private static Map<Byte, OpCode> valueToOpCode = new HashMap<>();

    static OpCode getOpCode(byte value) {
        return valueToOpCode.get(value);
    }

    public static enum OpCode {
        a((byte) 0x0),
        b((byte)0x18),
        c((byte)0x1A);            

        private byte value; 

        private  OpCode(byte value) {
            this.value = value;
            valueToOpCode.put(value, this);
        }

        byte getValue() {
            return value;
        }

    }

    private void test() {            
        byte x = 0x18;
        System.out.println(getOpCode(x)); // prints 'b'             
    }
```

Comment: You have to be very careful with the order of class initialization to get this to work. https://ideone.com/4N5pMA