# Instantiate class by passing required parameter depending on which environment you are in

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, enums

I have a below enum class which has few fields in it `stagePoolSize`, `prodPoolSize` and `enabled`.

```
  public enum Type {
    process_caty(5, 8, false), process_misc1(5, 8, false), link_entry(5, 12, true);
    private final int stagePoolSize;
    private final int prodPoolSize;
    private final boolean enabled;

    private Type(int stagePoolSize, int prodPoolSize, boolean enabled) {
      this.stagePoolSize = stagePoolSize;
      this.prodPoolSize = prodPoolSize;
      this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public int getStagePoolSize() {
      return stagePoolSize;
    }

    public int getProdPoolSize() {
      return prodPoolSize;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled() {
      return enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return name() + "=" + stagePoolSize + "=" + prodPoolSize + "=" + enabled;
    }
  }
```

And this is how I am using above enum to initialize my `Handler` class.

```
  private final List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<>();

  @PostConstruct
  public void postInit() {
    String datacenter = Utils.getDatacenter();

    for (Type consType : Type.values()) {
      if (!consType.isEnabled()) {
        continue;
      }
      int poolSize = Utils.isProd() ? consType.getProdPoolSize() : consType.getStagePoolSize();
      handlers.add(new Handler(consType, poolSize));
    }
  }
```

If  any of the enum is enabled, then depending on which environment (whether Prod or Stage) we are in by checking with this call `Utils.isProd()`, we get it's `poolSize` and then use that `poolSize` to initialize `Handler` class.

**Problem Statement:**

Now I need to add few more enums in the same `Type` class but I need to do something different for them. Below are the enums I need to add:

```
abc_raw_pho
abc_raw_slq
abc_raw_lvk
abc_raw_pin_pho
abc_raw_pin_slq
abc_raw_pin_lvk
```

Here is what we need to do for above new enums:

- It should only be used if the environment is `Prod`. And they will have some `prodPool` size value.
- And also if we are in `pho` datanceter, then we should use enums that ends with `pho`. And if we are in `slq` datacenter then we should use enums that ends with `slq`. Similarly for lvk.

I can figure out which datacenter we are in by calling this method:

```
    String datacenter = Utils.getDatacenter();
```

Now how should I design my `Type` enum class so that my original enum works as it is which is already there and also my new enum with datacenter in the end works with the above conditions. So below is the requirement overall:

- `process_caty` should be use both for `Stage` and `Prod` and it should use poolSize accordingly depending on what environment it is in.
- `process_misc1` should be use both for `Stage` and `Prod` and it should use poolSize accordingly depending on what environment it is in.
- `link_entry` should be use both for `Stage` and `Prod` and it should use poolSize accordingly depending on what environment it is in.
- `abc_raw_pho` should be use for `Prod` only but depending on which datacenter we are in and it should use poolSize for Prod only.
- `abc_raw_slq` should be use for `Prod` only but depending on which datacenter we are in and it should use poolSize for Prod only.
- `abc_raw_lvk` should be use for `Prod` only but depending on which datacenter we are in and it should use poolSize for Prod only.
- `abc_raw_pin_pho` should be for `Prod` only but depending on which datacenter we are in and it should use poolSize for Prod only.
- `abc_raw_pin_slq` should be for `Prod` only but depending on which datacenter we are in and it should use poolSize for Prod only.
- `abc_raw_pin_lvk` should be for `Prod` only but depending on which datacenter we are in and it should use poolSize for Prod only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your enum and break it down into smaller classes, introducing models for `Environment`, `DataCenter` and `PoolSizes`:

```
public enum Environment {PROD, STAGE}

public enum DataCenter {PHO, SLQ, LVK, NA /*Not applicable*/}

public class PoolSizes {

    public static final int SIZE_UNDEFINED = -1;

    private Map<Environment, Integer> environmentValues;

    public PoolSizes() {
        environmentValues = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public PoolSizes withStagePoolSize(int size) {
        environmentValues.put(Environment.STAGE, size);
        return this;
    }   

    public PoolSizes withProductionPoolSize(int size) {
        environmentValues.put(Environment.PROD, size);
        return this;
    }

    public int getPoolSize(Environment environment) {
        Integer size = environmentValues.get(environment);
        return size != null ? size : SIZE_UNDEFINED;            
    }        
}
```

The `Type` enum would then use these to simplify the logic for poolsize lookup and determining whether the type is enabled or not:

```
public enum Type {

    PROCESS_CATY(new PoolSizes().withStagePoolSize(5).withProductionPoolSize(8), 
        DataCenter.NA, false), 
    PROCESS_MISC1(new PoolSizes().withStagePoolSize(5).withProductionPoolSize(8), 
        DataCenter.NA, false), 
    LINK_ENTRY(new PoolSizes().withStagePoolSize(5).withProductionPoolSize(12), 
        DataCenter.NA, true),

    ABC_RAW_PHO(new PoolSizes().withProductionPoolSize(123), DataCenter.PHO, true),
    ABC_RAW_SLQ(new PoolSizes().withProductionPoolSize(123), DataCenter.SLQ, true),
    ABC_RAW_LVK(new PoolSizes().withProductionPoolSize(123), DataCenter.LVK, true),

    ABC_RAW_PIN_PHO(new PoolSizes().withProductionPoolSize(123), DataCenter.PHO, true),
    ABC_RAW_PIN_SLQ(new PoolSizes().withProductionPoolSize(123), DataCenter.SLQ, true),
    ABC_RAW_PIN_LVK(new PoolSizes().withProductionPoolSize(123), DataCenter.LVK, true);

    private final PoolSizes poolSizes;
    private final DataCenter dataCenter;
    private final boolean enabled;

    private Type(PoolSizes poolSizes, DataCenter dataCenter, boolean enabled) {
      this.poolSizes = poolSizes;
      this.dataCenter = dataCenter;
      this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    public int getPoolSize(Environment environment) {
      return poolSizes.getPoolSize(environment);
    }

    public DataCenter getDataCenter() {
        return this.dataCenter;
    }

    public boolean isEnabled(Environment environment, DataCenter dataCenter) {
      return enabled && poolSizes.getPoolSize(environment) != PoolSizes.SIZE_UNDEFINED 
              && (getDataCenter() == DataCenter.NA || getDataCenter() == dataCenter);
    }
  }
```

Finally, the `postInit()` method would become something like this:

```
public void postInit() {
    DataCenter dataCenter = Utils.getDataCenter();
    Environment environment = Utils.getEnvironment();

    for (Type consType : Type.values()) {
      if (!consType.isEnabled(dataCenter, environment)) {
        continue;
      }
      handlers.add(new Handler(consType, consType.getPoolSize(environment)));
    }
}
```

Comment: I see.. This makes sense now but now how my `postInit()` method will look like?

Comment: I added that one now (sorry, needed to post my answer quickly because of so many close-votes). You'd need to refactor `Utils` to return those enums.

Comment: Sure got it. Let me play with this for a while and will let you know if any confusion.

Comment: I guess there is one more change. In this line `handlers.add(new Handler(consType, consType.getPoolSize()));` we need to pass `environment` as well in `consType.getPoolSize()` right?

Comment: Yes, exactly; fixed that one now.

Comment: hey you still around?

Comment: Did you solve the problem already?

Comment: I might be available later today. In the meantime, I posted a question in the comments.